# Scrolling layout - like facebook or google plus right sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Any idea how make a layout like google plus or facebook. You can see at google plus home as example,

at the beginning, if you scroll the page in the main content, they will scroll together (friend post and sidebar), but when you scroll until the bottom of sidebar (in the right of friend post), that sidebar will stop scrolling , but the another content (friend post) will still scrolling. can explain to me how to make layout like that? sample code or demo will be very help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new approach with css3 is reduce your effort. use single property to get it.

```
position:sticky;
```

here is a article explained it and demo.

[article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)

[Demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed positioning with CSS is a very limited approach. There are a number of ways to do this style of "fixed" areas, many of which have already been given in answers to similar questions on here (try the search above?).

One technique (which many are based on) is like so (in brief)..

1. Capture the browser's scrolling
2. Get the position from top of chosen element (x)
3. Check if the scrolling > x, if so apply a class to the element to fix it to a certain position.

The same will work in reverse, for example:

```
var target = $('#div-to-stick');
var div_position = target.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() { 
    var y_position = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(y_position > div_position) {
        target.addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        target.removeClass('fixed');
    }
}
```

**Note:** Depending on how you chose to complete the code above, the page will often "jump" as the div's position is modified. This is not always a (noticeable) problem, but you can consider getting around this by using .before with target.height() and appending a "fake" replacement div with the same height.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for CSS `position:fixed` (for the scroll-along sidebar), you can set the location with `left:[length]`, `right:[length]`, `top:[length]`, `bottom:[length]` and the normal width and height combos

You will need to augment it with a window `resize` and `scroll` listener that applies the `position:fixed` property after the window has scrolled past the top of the sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

Use css property (position:fixed). This will keep the position of the div fixed even if you scroll down or scroll up.